# How to give a FileInputStream to a Videoview?

Tags: android, android-videoview, fileinputstream

I would like to know how to give a FileInputStream to a Videoview.
I can see that we have an API like setDataSource() for mediaplayer, in which you can give a file descriptor. Is this same kind of thing possible in videoView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to set a FileInputStream ?

use a [path](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/VideoViewDemo.html) or a [url](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setVideoURI%28android.net.Uri%29)

Just for your infomation VideoView i[s a thin wrapper over MediaPlayer](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java). So if you HAVE to do this go ahead and write your own custom VideoView.

Comment: __Why do you want to set a FileInputStream ?__ Why because, I have a buffered file which will should be given to player. This buffered file will be appended every time.

Comment: I assume (from your previous question) that this file is streamed from the net. So you can directly use that URL and the VideoView will stream the video.

Comment: I want to use FileInputStream because it's an internal file I am trying to play...

Comment: Have you been able to do it? I am planning to do the same thing